# Delete objects via reference c++

Tags: c++, memory-management

I  got this problem which I could not explain today.

```
int main(){
    vector<int> vec = subroutine();
    ...
    delete(&vec);
}

vector<int>& subroutine(){
    vector<int>* vec = new vector<int>();
    //Init the vec
    for(int i=0;i<vec.size();i++){
    ...
    }
    return *vec;
}
```

And it came with an error as:

```
double free or corruption (out): 0X00007fffa145ff50
```

It's definitely the problem with the line:

```
delete(&vec);
```

But I just can't explain, why there is a double free?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are calling `delete` on something that is not allocated with `new` because you are making a *copy* of the newed vector. You could "correct" your code by not copying the vector:

```
vector<int>& vec = subroutine();
```

but this kind of function really is asking for trouble. The correct way to fix this would be to return a vector by value.

```
vector<int> subroutine() {
    vector<int> vec;
    //Init the vec
    for(int i=0;i<vec.size();i++){
    ...
    }
    return vec;
}
```

Comment: Good answer, but an even better approach would be to pass `vec` in by reference and populated directly in `subroutine(vector<int> & vec)`  This avoids the copy that has to happen if `subroutine()` returns the vector by value.

Comment: @DaleWilson No, that would not be a better approach. It has no benefit at all because the return copy is elided, and you have to document the function and take care of the state of the input vector.

Answer (score 1):

When you return from the function, a copy of the vector is made and, at this point, the `new`ed memory is leaked and cannot be reached; hence the error, you are trying to delete something on the stack (and not on the heap).

I don't see a reason why you need the `new`; you could try this instead.

```
vector<int> subroutine(){
    vector<int> vec;
    //Init the vec
    for(int i=0;i<vec.size();i++){
    //...
    }
    return vec;
}
```

Return the `vector` by value.

Comment: @FredLarson Err... not it's not. Now it returns a reference to a local scope object. That is asking for a trouble.

Comment: I am sorry that does not work. A reference to a local variable is returned. The local vec will be deleted after the function is called.

Comment: @penpen926 It's already been corrected. It was an oversight. Thanks.

Comment: @FredLarson Oh, I saw, the comment, before the edit, and it's a ghost edit too. I dunno why I got comments updated before post.

Answer (score 0):

`vector<int> vec = subroutine();` here you make a copy. You do not return the pointer. You return a whole object that the pointer refers to, on this line `return *vec;`.

Thus, the `vec` from main is deleted explicitly by you, and then again when its scope ends.

Moreover, the `vec` from `subroutine` is never freed.